# IE9 FormsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, forms-authentication, internet-explorer-9

I had setup IE9 today and my FormsAuthentication stoped working.
My steps - create ASP.NET MVC2 Application in Visual Studio 2010, add Authorize attribute to HomeController, open AccontController and comment lines 44, 56, 58. Hit F5 enter user/user and hit ENTER, IE9 does not send authentication cookie to HomeController

```
    [HandleError, Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            //if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            //else
            {
                //ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a URL that reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to reproduce. Works perfectly fine for me. There must be some other problem with your setup. Did you verify if cookies were enabled?

Comment: Ok, thank you, IE9 setup by default had disabled cookies :). How I can can close this question ?